# When I link to MySql,if data is Chinese,then it gets Garbled

Tags: mysql, ios

I use my ios(Simutalor) to link to remote database.Code is as follows:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)query:(NSString *)sql
{
    if(!myconnect)
    {
        NSLog(@"Please connect first");
        return nil;
    }
    NSMutableArray *recordsArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    mysql_query(myconnect, [sql UTF8String]);
    MYSQL_RES* result = mysql_store_result(myconnect);
    int num_rows = mysql_num_rows(result);
    int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);

    for(int i=0;i<num_rows;i++)
    {
        MYSQL_ROW row = mysql_fetch_row(result);
        NSMutableArray *recordArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for(int j=0;j<num_fields;j++)
        { 
        if (row[j]==nil) {
            j++;
            [recordArr addObject:@""];
            continue;
            }
        NSString* value= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:row[j]];
    NSStringEncoding enc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingGB_18030_2000);
            [recordArr addObject:value];
        }       

        [recordsArray addObject:recordArr];
        [recordArr release];
    }
    return recordsArray;
}
```

If the value is Chinese,it will be showed by '?'.I hava tried may ways to encode,but I failed. 
Why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check character encoding on your front end as well as backend. If your backend encoding is correct, you still need to correct front end.

Comment: I have check character encoding.They are both using utf-8.